# ios ble central background cannot find ios ble peripheral background

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking for help on BLE ios.

I'm trying to make the BLE connection between 2 ios in background.

The problem is when ios peripheral in background, it hide the advertise uuid and make it only available for

- the ble scan without service uuid filter
- the ble scan from ios with that uuid filter

But when ble central in background, it can only scan peripheral with specific uuid filter

This make the ios central background cannot connect to ios peripheral background on other phone.

I did try to put the ble central in  background but it doesn't help

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(backgroundTask), name: UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification, object: nil)


@objc func backgroundTask() {
    setupClearDevicesTimer()
    self.stopScan()
    self.startScan()
    //setupClearDevicesTimer()
  }
```

Please help. I'm trying google for 3 days but found nothing.
Thank you.

Comment: Found something ? interesting topic.

Comment: thank for reminder. For now, this cannot be done with ios.